# HTML Image with clickable social media icons

Tags: html, css

I found some solutions for HTML clickable social media icons, but I want them as part of the image.

Comment: This is a static image right? It's a snapshot of another phone, is it still possible to create clickable images in this? or am i to create an image with the same information?

Answer (score 1):

@Emils Stopins, thanks so much for the help.

Like you said, mapping an image leads to clickable areas in an image. The trick is to find the exact coordinates of the clickable area in an image. 
I was able to get the desired result.

Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want links on an actual image, the easiest way is to make an [image map](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp).

Comment: so the text part of the image would be the same?

Comment: The image itself is not touched. Image map puts an overlay over an image where you can select regions you wish to be linked. Here is an example: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2b6dyjhr/)https://jsfiddle.net/2b6dyjhr/

Comment: as per the example, i should select the coordinates of the social media icons and edit them?

Comment: Please explain it in detail. i am not able to follow.

Comment: Yes, you need to select coords for the icons, and then change accordingly.

Comment: how do i find out the coordinates of the above image?

Comment: i found the coordinates to my image, how can i make them clickable now.

Comment: these are the coordinates.

Comment: <img src="url/to/your/image.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="216,528,263,527,210,575" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="200,514,266,522,301,525,222,575,266,576,308,579" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="196,513,266,529,330,526,205,583,280,577,322,579" />
    [...]
</map>

Comment: the coordinates that i obtain from the image, does it differ from the one that appears on the html editor after uploading the image?